# Flutter : Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-verification-id] The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to flutter. I was trying to make a small prototype in flutter where a user can login using the phone number and otp send using firebase. But i got stuck here and don't know how to solve the error. please help me to figure it out. Thanks.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:otp_login/OTP_Successful.dart';

class SendOtp extends StatefulWidget {
  static var verify="";
  const SendOtp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SendOtp> createState() => _SendOtpState();
}

class _SendOtpState extends State<SendOtp> {
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController otpController = TextEditingController();
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String? verificationId;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Send OTP"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: phoneController,
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter Phone Number"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
                    phoneNumber: "${phoneController.text}",
                    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
                    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
                    codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.verificationId = verificationId;
                      });
                      //SendOtp.verify = verificationId;
                      showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                              title: const Text('Enter OTP'),
                              content: TextFormField(
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "OTP"),
                              ),
                              actions: [
                                ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      print("Verification : $verificationId");
                                      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId!, smsCode: otpController.text);

                                      // Sign the user in (or link) with the credential
                                      await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
                                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>OtpSuccessful()));

                                    }, child: const Text("OK"))
                              ],
                            );
                          });
                    },
                    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
                  );

                },
                child: const Text("Send OTP"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the page where the user will enter his phone number including the country code (without any space) and will press the button 'Send OTP' and the OTP will send on his phone and simultaneously an alert box will open where the user has to enter the OTP and will press the button 'OK' on the press of which the user will push to send screen named 'OtpSucessful'.

I am getting the error on the press of the button of the alert box after entering the OTP. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the Verification id before using it for  `PhoneAuthProvider.credential()` is it printing proper?

Comment: Yes it is printing null

Comment: try changing either one of the variable names to avoid ambiguity and help in debugging the problem. Also add await for showDialog() and see if it helps.